# Play framework Testing controller

Tags: spring, junit, playframework

I am trying to test a controller using callAction
in ApplicationTest.java's testAction() method:

> Result result =
>   callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.action(463), request);

testAction(int) refers to some of the fields(mySpringService) in Application controller. How and where these fields to be instantiated? Can I have setup() in AplicationTest.java??

> public class Application extends Controller {
>   @Autowired    privateMySpringService mySpringService;
>
> public Result action(int waterQualityId){ 
>   mySpringService.doSomeMath();  return ok();  } 
>   }

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you should mock this service. Either you write your own dummy mySpringService or you use something like Mockito. Have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/JavaTest.

Comment: what if I have setter method to set an instance of mySpringService? I do not know how to call this setter method. I tried, but was not successful. Giving me compile errors

Comment: Could you please give an example of your MySpringService and your ApplicationTest?